How to Link C# Component with C++ winui3 controls
I want to call C# component winui3 controls in C++ Project , i have followed the steps which are givein in microsoft support but it is not executing
Steps i have tried.

First i have created the C# class library project
i have delected the .cs file
i have added new item User control under WinUI3 section.
in nuget package manager i have installed winui3 community control.
In CSProj file i have modied the cswinrtcomponent property as true.
updated few lines of code in usercontrol file.
I have created C++  Blank packaged winui project.
Added C# project reference to C++ project.
Updated pch.h File headers with c# project (#include <winrt/WinUIComponentCs.h>
#include <winrt/WinUIComponentCs.WinUIComponentCs_XamlTypeInfo.h>)
I have added Project path in Mainwindow.xaml.cpp
I have added Extesnsion of code in Package.appxmanifest
these are the steps i have followed iam getting below error :

 Exception thrown at 0x762CA892 in SampleCPP27.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x00B3AC60.


You should first follow this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/create-windows-runtime-component-cswinrt and only after it works, start changing it.
